# Retrieve rows, return only user selected columns from the list

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I need to retrieve columns which will be decided by user at run-time.
Lets assume EmpTable > EmpID, EmpName, EmpDesignation

All column will be listed in list. And then User will be select the column which he wanna to be export.

Can we achieve using Linq?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a model created for your database on which you use LINQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String myQuery = "select "; 

// build your query with selected items
var result = datacontext.ExecuteQuery(myQuery);
```